# How come I can't input a formula into my Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

Here are my steps: focus a cell in my Google Spreadsheet, hit <kbd>=</kbd> and then highlight the field D3, hit <kbd>+</kbd>, highlight the field D4, hit <kbd>+</kbd>, highlight the field D5, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

However, the field just contains the text "=D3+D4+D5" instead of the sum of the selected cells. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance that you have told Google docs to show formulas.

<kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> will toggle the display of the formulas

or

it is under the "view /all formulas" menu.